# Invalid prop `center` supplied to `GoogleMap`. React.js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

im trying to intialize google maps using google maps react library 
and wanted the map to change every time i search for a location based on the latitude and longitude state. However im receving an error saying invalid prop center supplied to google maps react. For some reason It works when i place in a number instead of this.state... Can someone pls help ?

App.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from "axios";
    import './App.css';
    import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete'
    import { geocodeByAddress, geocodeByPlaceId, getLatLng } from 'react-places-autocomplete'
    import UserForm from "./components/UserForm.js";

    import Super from "./components/super.js";


    import MapContainer from './components/Map.js'
    import Map from './components/Map.js';
    import { classnames } from './components/helpers';

    const google = window.google;



    class App extends Component {
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          zoom: 13,
          maptype: 'roadmap',
          place_formatted: '',
          place_id: '',
          place_location: '',
          address: '',
          latitude: '37.774929',
          longitude: '-122.419416'

        };
      }

    <div>
    <Map center= {{lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude}}
          />
              <div>

        );
      }
    };

export default App;
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'
import marker from './marker.png'

import {geolocated} from 'react-geolocated';
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div><img src={marker} style={{height:'50px',width:'50px'}}/></div>;
export default class Map extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {

    zoom: 11
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div className='google-map' style={{width: '100%',height: '400px',backgroundColor: 'grey'}}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          center={ this.props.center }
          defaultZoom={ this.props.zoom }>
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={ this.props.center.lat}
            lng={ this.props.center.lng }
            text={ '' }
          />

        </GoogleMapReact>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not wrap your `latitude` and `longitude`  by quote. When you wrap those with quote `''`  it convert latitude, longitude type `number` to `string`. So your latitude, longitude attribute should declare like

```
latitude: 37.774929,
longitude: -122.419416
```

instead of

```
    latitude: '37.774929',
    longitude: '-122.419416'
```

So your state should be following

```
        this.state = {
          zoom: 13,
          maptype: 'roadmap',
          place_formatted: '',
          place_id: '',
          place_location: '',
          address: '',
          latitude: 37.774929,
          longitude: -122.419416

        };
```

Comment: This would have taken ages to crack. You saved me!